# php7 extension mmap out of memory?

Tags: php, linux, out-of-memory, mmap, php-extension

I'm trying to convert a php5.x extension for php7, compiled fine now but when I ran the test cases, every single one of them are dying with:

```
mmap() failed: [22] Invalid argument
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 18446744073709551608 bytes)
```

Their wiki (https://wiki.php.net/phpng-upgrading) didn't really mentioned anything about mmap when upgrading, and Google didn't give me much hint on this issue either.

I've enabled HugePage on the server but that doesn't help either. Could someone give me some hint?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve lately? :-) Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your input @shellter but I don't think I can start posting the entire extension out, besides, this is more of a general question to people who've upgrade their extension with custom object from php5 to php7... If have a reduced test case, I would've just fix the bug myself.

Comment: Without a way to easily reproduce your issue, many readers will skip this Q (IMHO). Aren't there PHP dev specific lists and forums where these low-level issues are dealt with?  In any case, I hope you solve your problem. Good luck!